# Decomposition of a group manifold; is there an associated group decomposition?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups

The real symplectic group manifold is diffeomorphic to this Cartesian product of manifolds: 
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R}) \simeq \operatorname{U}(n) \times \mathbb{R}^{n(n+1)}.
\end{equation}
from Arnol'd and Givental's 'Symplectic Geometry'.

> **EDIT 1:** Is there a group isomorphism that fits this diffeomorphic breakdown? i.e. a decomposition of $\operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$ into $\operatorname{U}(n)$ and something else.

**EDIT 2:** With its lack of normal subgroups, by decomposition I mean a more general product like Zappa-Szép.

Comment: There are problems on the RHS if you wanted to write a product; there are lots of Lie groups diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$ but not isomorphic; the Heisenberg groups are one class of examples. Even if you included all of those as options on the RHS, I don't know if you can compose your Lie group as some sort of product.

Comment: @MikeMiller. Ah, I see. I was very mistakenly assuming that this diffeomorphic decomposition would necessarily translate into some sort of isomorphic decomposition. Thank you very much.

Comment: Incidentally I would still be interested to know if there is a group isomorphism that fits this decomposition. (i.e. U(n) and something else).

Comment: Yes - I don't have an answer for that, which is why I posted the above as a comment. I hope someone else has something to say.

Comment: (I deleted my answer in light of your edit.)  With regards to the edit, I would no longer be surprised is $Sp(2n,\mathbb{R})$ had such a decomposition, but I don't know how to prove or disprove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diffeomorphism $\operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R}) \simeq \operatorname{U}(n) \times \mathbb{R}^{n(n+1)}$ comes from the polar decomposition of a generic symplectic matrix. This uniquely splits $S \in \operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$ into $KP$ where $K \in \operatorname{OSp}(2n,\mathbb{R}) = \operatorname{O}(2n) \cap \operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$ and $P$ is from the *set* of positive definite symmetric symplectic matrices. This latter set is not a Lie group but it does have manifold structure.